# Writing a parallel for loop

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm confused as to how to declare which parts of a program are accessible or not from the different workers. On a relatively low level in a program of mine I have a for loop I want to parallelize.

```
module module_name
[...]
addprocs(3)
totalsum = @parallel (+) for i in 1:large_number
    tmp_sum = 0
    for j in 1:num
        ...  # calls f1 f2
    end
    tmp_sum  # not sure how to 'return' the result, the examples have a conveniantly placed calculation at the end
end
rmprocs([2 3 4])
[...]
end
```

As I understand I'd have to put the `@everywhere` decorator infront of `f1` and `f2`. But the program fails far before with the additional workers complaining that `UndefVarError: module_name not defined`, and I have no clue how to fix that.

I feel like I’ve missed something needed for setting up parallel processing. As I understood it other than writing the actual `@parallel` part, one needs to addprocs and then add the `@everywhere` decorator to those functions used inside the loop. Is that really it?

I know `pmap` is better suited for what I'm doing here but I wanted to get the simpler option to work first (I'd need to pass several arguments the `pmap` function).

Comment: It looks like you are doing actual work in the module. That's a bit unusual. Generally, modules are there to store functions and type declarations. Then work is done in a script where the module is loaded with `@everywhere using MyModule`. A module should never contain `addprocs` in it directly.

Comment: I don't quite understand. My module contains several functions, one of which has the code I show here (which is in reality indented a couple levels, but indenting is fucking hard in markdown so I didn't bother). The `[...]` is supposed to signify a bunch of other stuff that I've omitted because it adds no useful information. I don't actually have code running outside of a function.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you don't want @everywhere in front of function declarations inside the module, but rather right before importing the module from a script or the REPL: '@everywhere using module_name'

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out. Your comment has also made me look at some julia repos and realize that it seems most functions are kept in `.jl` files that are not modules (I thought every `.jl` one used had to be a module).